# Android: Preview picture after capture, before save

Tags: android

I got a full camera app up and running, but I'd like to have the captured picture show on the screen before saving them (they're not going to the gallery). I've googled extensively and I can't find anything on the topic. I also have no idea how to start, so any advice or links to relevant information I didn't find would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: How do you have full camera app without having access to the image? (read: how do you obtain and save the image?)

Comment: Its being saved to the gallery. I mean I want the image to be displayed with the option to save or cancel back to the camera to retake. I'm fairly new to android so if I apologize if its a very obvious answer that I'm just overlooking

Comment: So you are using the camera application to take the picture (it's not your application taking it)?

Comment: Ohh no its a custom application. I have a method that creates a directory in the gallery for now, and then another method that takes the media file and saves it to said directory

Comment: So if you have a method that takes the media file, why don't you display it and ask the user?

Comment: I guess that's my problem, how would I display it? Do I have to use a Bitmap or can I put it straight onto the surface display?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming you are using the original [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) APIs, not [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). That functionality is really built into the preview capturing, so I'm assuming your code is just clearing the preview too quickly.

After calling `Camera.startPreview()` to render the live preview on the active surface, at some point `Camera.takePicture()` is called to trigger the image capture and the result is returned to the `PictureCallback`. As soon as the image is captured, the camera preview surface is frozen on that frame until it is restarted. So as long as you don't call `Camera.startPreview()` again inside of `onPictureTaken()` to restart that process, the `SurfaceView` will remain frozen on the frame you want the user to see already.

Then if they want to save, you can write the JPEG data to disk, and if not toss away the data.

Comment: Dude...I love you. I would upvote but I need one more reputation -_- I guess an accepted answer will have to do for now

Comment: Is there any harm in using Camera API 1 instead of 2 now (in 2019+) ? like on new devices that have Android 8+.

Comment: On lock/onlocking the screen the frozen image is replaced by live camera since startpreview is called in onResume. Is there a way to preserve the image on app resume?